# Combining Bostock's Constrained Zoom and Bounding Box

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I'm trying to integrate a constrained zoom (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4987520) into the example featuring Bounding Box (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9656675).
The point is to get the same behavior as the Bounding Box example while constraining the window zoom (and also being able to move around/zoom in/zoom out with the mouse which is already done in the given example).

I've been trying out and also found examples (not aiming to do the exact same thing though) but nothing worked as expected.
My code  can be boiled down to the one in the Bounding Box, with the following "move" function :

```
var t = d3.event.translate,
    s = d3.event.scale;
t[0] = Math.min(0,Math.max(t[0],width - width*s));
t[1] = Math.min(0,Math.max(t[1],height - height*s));
zoom.translate(t);
g.style("stroke-width", 1/s).attr("transform","translate(" + t + ")scale(" + s + ")");
```

Now the behavior I get almost meets the requirements except that when clicking on a specific state to zoom in on it, the view abruptly recenters on the previous clicked state before smoothly moving into the new chosen one.
Strangely enough, removing the "zoom.translate(t)" in the previous code fixes the bug but gives an "over-constrained" feeling to the manual zoom, i.e some areas are not reachable by zooming in and the "camera" translates in a peculiar way making it also impossible to zoom out - the zoom view is somehow attracted by the current selected state.

If someone knows how to work it out to get the expected behavior, I'll be thrilled.

Thanks in advance,
Killian.